# Atuodesk Inventor VBA to read excel

Tags: excel, vba

My code below started giving error after office365 was installed on my machine.

```
Private Sub btnUpdateInfo_Click()
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application 
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Error here
        
Dim ProjectPath As String
Dim OpenAt As String
'Get full name of current project (including Project name)
ProjectPath = ThisApplication.DesignProjectManager.ActiveDesignProject.FullFileName
'Get location string only from above
OpenAt = GetFilePath(ProjectPath)
'add location ahead of excel file containing project information. File to be copied to same folder 
where project file resides.
ProjectPath = OpenAt & "ProjectDetail.xlsx"
            
' Open the workbook.
Dim workBook As workBook
Set workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(ProjectPath)
' Get the sheet.
Dim sheet As WorkSheet
Set sheet = workBook.Sheets.Item("Sheet1")
    
' Get some values.
Dim val1 As String
val1 = sheet.Cells(1, 2)
Dim val2 As String
val2 = sheet.Cells(2, 2)
projNo.Value = val1
projName.Value = val2
    
'Close it down.
excelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Error says: [image]

excel version:
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13929.20222) 64-bit
Invenotr2019 Build 330

I have fixed office365 installation but still same. Any idea how can I resolve it?
regards,
Sam

Comment: Which line throws the error? Have you checked content of variables `ProjectPath` and `OpenAt`? Is the workbook opened? Does it have a sheet `Sheet1`?

Comment: It's essential that you should disclose which line of your code is highlighted when the error occurs. Please modify your question to include this information and you are likely to have a quick answer.

Comment: @FunThomas Sorry I missed that. 3rd line of code. Edited the post.

Comment: @FunThomas It does have a sheet Sheet1. I guess it is having trouble firing up excel.

Comment: @Variatus sorry I missed that.

Comment: Try to declare `ExcelApp As Object`. But from which application are you calling this procedure? If it's called from Excel, are you sure you need a second instance of it?

Comment: @Variatus It is not excel it is another application Atudoesk Inventor

Comment: In that case it's the Autodesk app that has the problem with Excel. The error indicates that a reference is missing. After loading the program, select Tools > References in the VB Editor, look for a reference marked "Missing", and enable it. This is provided that the Autodesk app works like Excel in this regard. An expert on Autodesk Inventor will be of greater use than I can be. You may like to add an appropriate tag to your question.